# Why is past simple used in this sentence?

Tags: past-tense, usage

> Cameron **worked** for this computer company for ten years and then he found a better-paid job.

Why is past simple used here?

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't be?

Comment: Because it refers to a past time situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Answer (score 3):

The simple past is preferred.  We can still use the past perfect, but it is unnecessary as the sequence of events is clear: the *finding* happened after the *working*.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you mean "Why *isn't* the past perfect used, when one past incident happened before another?"

The simple past tense is fine when you are merely listing two things that happened. If the writer had wanted to emphasise the order of events, they could have said

> Cameron had worked at the computer company for ten years **before** he found a better-paid job.

Comment: In your last example, you might say that the perfect is redundant because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by "before".