# Past continuous with long actions

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous

When I want to emphasize a fact about my past, it's a lot more natural to say

I played tennis for 10 years

I was playing tennis for 10 years

When I tell a story it's not so important any more

When I met her, I played tennis for ten years

I met her while I was playing tennis for ten years

Are these two are equally fine?

Comment: What are "When I met her, I played tennis for ten years" and "I met her while I was playing tennis for ten years" supposed to mean? You had already played for ten years when you met her, or you were in the middle of your ten-year tennis career? Neither sounds natural. (The last sounds like you were playing for ten years without ever stopping.)

Comment: In the middle..

Comment: How would you say it?

Comment: I would say, "I met her during the ten years that I played tennis."

Comment: There's no meaningful connection between the *duration* of an activity and the choice between Simple Past / Past Continuous. The choice of verb form depends *entirely* on other contextual factors.

Comment: Related [Why is past simple used in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345649/why-is-past-simple-used-in-this-sentence) “*Cameron **worked** for this computer company for ten years and then he found a better-paid job.*"

Answer (score 1):

SIMPLE PAST

> “I **met** her **while** I was a professional tennis player.”

If playing tennis was just a hobby why mention it in the first place? There are dozens of things someone might be doing at any given time. A more likely use of the Past Continuous would be to refer to one's residence.

PAST CONTINUOUS

> "**I was living** in Missouri **when** we met for the first time.”

This suggests that the speaker no longer lives in Missouri. If the OP wants to emphasise the length of time they could say:

PAST PERFECT CONTINUOUS

> **I had been living** in Missouri **for ten** months/years when I met my future wife.

In this instance, the speaker had lived in Missouri for ten months/years  *before* they met. We don't know enough to surmise whether the speaker is still living there.

Likewise the OP's sentence “When I met her, I played tennis for ten years” should be:

> *When I met her, I **had been playing** tennis for ten years*

Elsewhere in a related question, [the OP asks](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346742/do-we-use-the-past-continuous-with-long-actions?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment673093_346746)

> I just want to know if it's okay to say “While I was working 10 years I bought a house”? Yes or no that's it.

1. ***I was working*** *in Germany **when** I bought a house.*
2. *I bought a house* **while** ***I was working** in Germany*

There is no need to specify the duration, the act of purchasing a home occurred during that specific period–working in Germany.

This is because we don't normally use the PRESENT CONTINUOUS to say how long an action lasts.

3. "I **am working** in Germany for ten years” NO

Instead, we'd use the PRESENT PERFECT or the PRESENT PERFECT CONTINUOUS

4. I **have lived** / **been living** in Germany for ten years. YES